# Deploying SXA 10.2 XM Single with Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.7 - The declared parameter 'Application Path" is not recognized

Tags: sxa, installation

Installing XMScaled with modules is not working as expected. This did not work for XMSingle too. Followed the [Walkthrough](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--deploying-a-new-sitecore-environment-to-the-microsoft-azure-app-service.html) and inputs from [Sitecore Azure Quickstart Templates](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates)

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Failed","message":"ARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared parameter 'Application Path' is not recognized.\r\n\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.LoadSetParameters(DeploymentObject deploymentObject, IDictionary`2 setParams, String setParamXmlFile)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__25.MoveNext()'"}]}
```

Please share any ideas, tips on this

Comment: Did you use SPE `.scwdp.zip` with IAR support (items as resources)?

Comment: No the url is IAR https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/D1EDF3410DA34E109CBACAFD424952EC.ashx?date=20211103T111147